# JPA Hibernate - How to prevent saving @ManyToOne associated entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I got User entity:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

And Address entity:

```
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Long userId;
}
```

When I save Address entity, Hibernate is trying to update User record. How to forbid Hibernate doing that?

I create new Address like this:

```
@Override
public void createAddress(Address address) {
    addressRepository.save(address);
}
```

Where Address is:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "fullName": "name",
  "address_line1": "address",
  "address_line2": "address2",
  "postal": "postalcode",
  "city": "city",
  "region": "region",
  "country": "country"
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the code that fetches User/Address and updates them?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I've updated the question. The problem appears only when I'm trying to save Address. Hibernate retrieve User by given ID parameter and tries to save it back into repository. How do I know? The thing is User password has been prevented from deserialization. So whenever I fetch User the response doesn't contain a password info. Thus when I save Address I got exception which tells that password is mandatory and can't be omitted. Which meant Hibernate is trying to save retrieved entity and I don't need that.

Comment: You say that `User` entity is updated. You show how `Address` is saved. But you don't show how `User` object is created (fetched from DB?) and how it's updated with new values - that's the most important information here.

Comment: Information on which Hibernate version (exactly) is used in your scenario can also be helpful to others. Please edit/update the Q and provide these details.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev You actually helped a lot by asking me that question :) I started looking for the problems in other parts of the code and find out the old code which should've been deleted a long time ago. The problem was in getUserById method where I left this: "user.setPassword("")". After a while I added @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) to password field but forgot to delete old workaround. Now adding Address works perfectly!

Comment: Okay, happy to help :)